# Boost::Asio Transferred bytes while using an async operation

Tags: c++, asynchronous, server, progress-bar, boost-asio

I'm using `Boost::Asio` HTTP Server 3 example (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)
but I need some "download information" such as number of transferred bytes in a certain amount of time in order to show a progress bar. 
But how can I get this information if I'm using the `boost::asio::async_write` function? I know that I can access to `boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred` in the `handle_write` completion handler but it is called just once asynchronous write operation has finished. 
There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use the composed operation (`boost::async_*`).

Instead, roll your own composed operation that uses `service_object.async_read_some` repeatedly and report the progress where you want it.

- http://vinniefalco.github.io/beast/beast/core/tutorial.html